# Rails exec_query bindings ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to use `exec_query` to run an arbitrary query, with values brought in through bindings, and am getting unexpected errors.

Running this in the console

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM foobars WHERE id IN (?)'
name = 'query_name_placeholder'
binds = [FooBar.first]
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query sql, name, binds
```

Yields this error:

```
Account Load (7.9ms)  SELECT  "foobars".* FROM "foobars"  ORDER BY "foobars"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM foobars WHERE id IN (?)
                                             ^
: SELECT * FROM foobars WHERE id IN (?)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM foobars WHERE id IN (?)
                                             ^
: SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id IN (?)
from /Users/foo_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@foo_project/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:641:in `prepare'
```

It appears the binding syntax is being ignored? I've tried `... WHERE id = ?` as well, but to no avail.

Comment: `exec_query` is part of the low level driver interface so you have to use the database's native placeholders, in PostgreSQL's case that would be `$1`, `$2`, ... Once you get past that you'll probably encounter a `NoMethodError` because `binds` isn't what is expected; I have no idea what `binds` is supposed to look like as none of this stuff is documented and the code behind it is the usual incomprehensible defusenss that you find inside Rails.

Answer (score 34):

mu is too short got you part of the way there. For reference, here is the method's documentation: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/exec_query

He's right in that you will need to use the underlying database's binds syntax to set bind variables in the SQL string. For Oracle this is `:1, :2` for PostgreSQL this is `$1, $2...` so that's step one.

Step two is you need to build bind *objects*, which are QueryAttribute objects, not just values to be passed in. This is a bit clunky, but here's an example:

```
binds = [ ActiveRecord::Relation::QueryAttribute.new(
    "id", 6, ActiveRecord::Type::Integer.new
)]
ApplicationRecord.connection.exec_query(
    'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', 'sql', binds
)
```

I just spent a whole day going through unit tests and source code trying to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks for going to all that trouble. Database access in Ruby is pretty awful when you step outside the usual boxes.

Comment: No problem, I had to figure it out for my own stuff too. I was just surprised at how hard it was to do something that should have been so simple. At least on oracle_enhanced, it's actually simpler to just use the underlying OCI8 adapter.

Comment: do we need to pass prepare: true ? and what is the difference between false and true?

Comment: @AndreyKhataev where would you pass prepare: true? exec_query doesn't have that options hash. It's just the query, a name for caching, and a list of binds that match the binds in the query itself.

Comment: @Michael I was confused by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51372969 and this documentation https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_query - here we can see prepare parameter

Comment: They seem to have essentially the same answer with the extra optional keyword argument. I wasn’t aware of it, and I’ve been using the binds no problem with Oracle without prepare.

Comment: @AndreyKhataev and Michael, prepared statements aren't about changing the results; they provide performance efficiency for queries that will be repeated often, and they provide a measure of security against sql injection attacks.  You can get the general (database-agnostic) idea here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement  and some relevant sample code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51372969

Comment: @JoelFouse Doesn't Oracle do that anyway with bound variables? If you're using :1, :2... I was under the impression it already parsing and caching the query.